# identifying rows having common values in two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

How to identify rows having same values in two columns (here: `treatment`, `replicate`) at least in another one row?

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rep(1:10, 4)
y <- sample(c(rep(1:10, 2)+rnorm(20)/5, rep(6:15, 2) + rnorm(20)/5))
treatment <- sample(gl(8, 5, 40, labels=letters[1:8]))
replicate <- sample(gl(8, 5, 40))
d <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, treatment=treatment, replicate=replicate)

table(d$treatment, d$replicate)

#   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
# a 1 0 0 1 1 2 0 0
# b 1 1 0 0 1 2 0 0
# c 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 2
# d 2 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
# e 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 1
# f 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
# g 0 1 0 2 0 0 1 1
# h 1 0 2 0 0 0 1 1
```

From the above output, my guess is that the output should contain 16 rows. Any idea how to achieve this?

Update:

```
d %>% group_by(treatment, replicate) %>% filter(n()>1)
# A tibble: 16 x 4
       x         y treatment replicate
   <int>     <dbl>    <fctr>    <fctr>
 1     2  7.050445         h         3
 2     5  1.840198         b         6
 3     8  9.160838         d         1
 4     9  4.254486         h         3
 5     2  8.870106         g         4
 6     4  7.821616         a         6
 7     6  9.752492         e         2
 8     7  9.988579         c         5
 9     9 10.480931         c         8
10     1  2.770469         c         8
11     2  7.913338         e         2
12     3 13.743080         d         1
13     9  5.692010         b         6
14    10 11.100722         a         6
15     3 12.198432         g         4
16     5  5.955146         c         5
```

I have identified one approach where the results seem to satisfy the condition. Any other better solutions?

Comment: What do you mean "having same values"?

Comment: For example in the latest output, row 1, 4 have same values in columns treatment, replicate.

Comment: Are you trying to add a column to the `data.frame`?

Comment: If there is an option of creating a new column `treatment_replicate` with values combined, then it is an added advantage. 
(Actually, It was my follow-up question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` as a condition:

```
dups <- d[which(duplicated(d[,c("treatment", "replicate")]) | 
                duplicated(d[ ,c("treatment", "replicate")], fromLast = TRUE)),]

>dups
        x         y treatment replicate
2   2  7.050445         h         3
5   5  1.840198         b         6
8   8  9.160838         d         1
9   9  4.254486         h         3
12  2  8.870106         g         4
14  4  7.821616         a         6
16  6  9.752492         e         2
17  7  9.988579         c         5
19  9 10.480931         c         8
21  1  2.770469         c         8
22  2  7.913338         e         2
23  3 13.743080         d         1
29  9  5.692010         b         6
30 10 11.100722         a         6
33  3 12.198432         g         4
35  5  5.955146         c         5
```